# page navigation in Kitchen Sink navigation

Tags: extjs

I have developed an application based on the kitchen sink design in sencha touch 1.
In that for a list on itemDisclosure I need to navigate to another js page having a menu.For example if it is a employee list, by clicking on particular employee I should get a different page having a menu of **salary details**,**leave details** etc.

```
    demos.List = new Ext.Panel ({
layout : 'fit',
    cls: 'demo-list',
    items: [{
        width: Ext.is.Phone ? undefined : 300,
        height: Ext.is.Phone ? undefined : 500,
        xtype: 'list',
        store: demos.ListStore, //getRange(0, 9),
        itemTpl: '<div class="contact"><strong>{firstName}</strong> {lastName}</div>',
        onItemDisclosure: function(record, btn, index) {
            Ext.Msg.alert('Tap', 'Disclose more info for ' +  record.get('firstName'));
             ---- From here I want to open a new page ----
             ---- I am following Kitchen Sink architecture -----

            }

    }]
/*}]*/
```

});

i have to navigate to the employeeMenu.js

Can anyone help me out for the same?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Animesh ,you have to add the employeeMenu in items,like below

```
items: [{
        width: Ext.is.Phone ? undefined : 300,
        height: Ext.is.Phone ? undefined : 500,
        xtype: 'list',
        store: demos.ListStore, //getRange(0, 9),
        itemTpl: '<div class="contact"><strong>{firstName}</strong> {lastName}</div>',
        onItemDisclosure: function(record, btn, index) {
            Ext.Msg.alert('Tap', 'Disclose more info for ' +  record.get('firstName'));
             ---- From here I want to open a new page ----
             ---- I am following Kitchen Sink architecture -----

            }

    },{employeeMenu}]
```